# Java - How many combination of numbers

Tags: java, numbers, combinations

Anyone can give me an idea how I approach calculating in Java the following problem. How many possible valid numbers, where a valid number is any number between 0-9, length of 10 digits,  excluding # or *,  a piece of Chess can trace while travelling across a telephone keypad. Here say I have a King, it can move only as in a real game, in any direction but only a single cell at a time.

So the keypad looks like this:

```
         1  2  3
         4  5  6
         7  8  9
         *  0  #
```

So the piece makes 10 moves each time and each unique number created by it is a valid number. A piece starts its journey from an initial starting position.

UPDATE: 
A piece can move or stay in one place (where moving or staying will both count as a move) as well as revisit the cells (as long as its allowed within their respective moving rights). So for example if a King moves from position 1 a three valid 10-move paths to create a valid number number could be 1236547890 or 1111111111 or 1212121212

Here's the code for a small version of four celled square pad with just 4 cells just for the purpose of testing:

```
public class King
{
private static final Integer[] ALLOWED_FROM_1 = {2, 3, 4};
private static final Integer[] ALLOWED_FROM_2 = {1, 3, 4};
private static final Integer[] ALLOWED_FROM_3 = {1, 2, 4};
private static final Integer[] ALLOWED_FROM_4 = {1, 2, 3};
List<Integer> visited;

public King()
{
    this.visited = new ArrayList<Integer>();

}

public List<Integer> get_destinations(int currentPos, int noOfMoves)
{
    if (noOfMoves == 0)
    {
        visited.add(currentPos);
        return visited;

    }
    else
    {

        List<Integer> possibleMoves = getPossibleMoves(currentPos);

        for (int i = 0; i < possibleMoves.size(); i++)
        {
            visited.add(possibleMoves.get(i));
            get_destinations(possibleMoves.get(i), noOfMoves - 1);

        }

        return visited;
    }



}


private List<Integer> getPossibleMoves(int currentPos)
{

    List<Integer> possibleMoves = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    switch (currentPos)
    {
        case 1 : possibleMoves.addAll(Arrays.asList(ALLOWED_FROM_1));
            break;

        case 2: possibleMoves.addAll(Arrays.asList(ALLOWED_FROM_2));
            break;

        case 3 : possibleMoves.addAll(Arrays.asList(ALLOWED_FROM_3));
            break;

        case 4 : possibleMoves.addAll(Arrays.asList(ALLOWED_FROM_4));
    }

    return possibleMoves;

}
}
```

The code above produces only partial answer with many different permutations missing. The main question is how exactly can I ensure that it produces all permutations as well as at what moment precisely in the above code do I reach the 4 digit number (after 4 moves) that should be stored and later retrieved. Also how can I avoid revisiting of the same sequences e.g 1234 1234 , so basically optimize it so it won't produce same path sequences/valid numbers.

All help much appreciated.

Comment: What piece of chess? Any one of these? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is there a fixed starting position?

Comment: Sounds like homework, care to add the corresponding tag if so?

Comment: If it can't revisit a cell the maximum number of moves that can be made is 9 (king or queen).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo-code that might help. You can solve the problem recursively with something like this:

```
// Returns a list of all the destinations given a current location
// and the number of moves allowed (10 for King)
list<int> get_destinations(int cur_location, int num_moves) {
  // Base case. If no more moves are allowed, return current location as list.
  if(num_moves == 0) {
    return as_list(cur_location);
  } else {
    // List of all destinations possible from here
    list<int> destinations;
    // Get all the possible moves that are 1 step away.
    // For example: from 1, we would return 2 and 4
    list<int> possible_moves = get_possible_moves(cur_location);

    // For each of the moves generated from the last step,
    // recursively call get_destinations() with (num_moves - 1)
    for(int n:possible_moves) {
      destinations += get_destinations(n, num_moves - 1);
    }

    return destinations;
  }
}
```

You would then call this function with something like this:

```
get_unique_nums(get_destinations); // Returns the set in the form you need it
```

Good luck with your homework!

Comment: Thanks Mike .. I've tried similar solution but got lost around recursion.. I'll try again with your pseudo code  for template and will let you know how it went ..

Comment: I've tried with the above pseudo code but getting repeated paths... I've tried on a smaller keyboard with just four keys 1,2,3,4 in square with get_destinations(1, 4) .. it returns 120/4 so 30 combinations but when checked I see repeated paths .. here for example is the first 4 paths, you can see that the second and fourth are same ->> 2, 1, 2, 1, **3, 4, 3, 1**, 2, 3, 4, 2, **3, 4, 3, 1**  .. how can I prevent  this

Comment: How is `getPossibleMoves` defined?

Comment: Sorry ..I've included the rest of the King class above

Comment: @foofighter: Your basecase returns empty list, when it should return the current element. Furthermore, you seem to be missing cases from 5+. The cases you have currently put there actually seem wrong. Surely what is reachable from 1 is actually `{2, 4, 5}`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like quite trivial academic recursion problem. Language should not matter, as long as recursions are allowed.

you need:

1. Set up 
   a. The F(n,m) array (with the values 3x4 in your case) 
   b. and an initial position of the piece.
   c. to allow arbitrary pieces you may want to define delegate(function pointer, anonymous class) function that defines allowable moves
2. Create a recursively callable function for identifying next eligible positions that takes as an input :
   a. current piece position (i, j), 
   b. the recursion depth 1 in the first iteration
3. Return back from the recursive function on the depth = 10
4. If you need also all the sequences, make this recursive function returnable (non void type) I'd say string would be the best
5. If you want to make it simpler to code you don't need to verify presence of *, # on every step in the set of allowable cells, just verify final 10 symbols long string to be parse-able as UNSIGNED LONG. Though it make the recursion too long.

Comment: Okay. But why `Return back from the recursive function on the depth = 10`?. Return as soon as no valid moves are left (which would be at most 10).

Answer (score 0):

For a king, this repetition is coming.
2, 1, 2, 1, **3, 4, 3, 1**, 2, 3, 4, 2, **3, 4, 3, 1**

You can make the getPossibleMove() function to return the cells in a particular order.
This will help avoid repetition of path. Say in the numeric order only, it should then return

2, 1, 2, 1,
2, 1, 2, 3,
2, 1, 2, 5,
2, 1, 4, 1,
2, 1, 4, 5,
2, 1, 4, 7

Moreover, if you do not want to allow the piece to move to the same cell, just remove those cells in the getPossibleMove() function only.

I didn't get what code to write, so wrote only theoretical explanation.

Comment: Hi Shashwat .. thanks for your comment , yeah the question though is what particular order ..as you see from the attached code I've put the cells in numerical order and this is when I get the result with repetition like we the one you just described and I had before ..I was really hoping to play with it last night as I need it asap for today but the sleep got the better of me after last few days work .. so brewing fresh cuppa and trying to get it to work as I write ..